# Bot Framework - how to access entity defined in partial class

Tags: c#, properties, botframework, entity

I exported my LUIS app contents (.json) and generated a .cs code from it using `bf luis:generate:cs` command:

```
public partial class AssistantRootDialog: IRecognizerConvert
{
```

and wrote another partial class to access the entities a better (named) way

```
public partial class AssistantRootDialog
{
  public String PhoneUser => Entities?.ContactName?.FirstOrDefault() ?? "<no user>";
   ...
}
```

in my Adaptive Dialog I set the LUI recongized intent and entity as the following:

```
new OnIntent(nameof(AssistantRootDialog.Intent.LookForMobilePhone)) {
   Actions = new List<Dialog>() {
     new SetProperty() {
       Property = "conversation.find.phone.userName",
       Value = "=turn.recognized.Entities?.ContactName[0]"
     },
```

I wonder how can I use the `PhoneUser` property from the partial class:

```
     new SetProperty() {
       Property = "conversation.find.phone.userName",
       Value = "=turn.recognized.PhoneNumber"  // It seems wrong !! ??
     },
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I try to achieve: get the value of the entity attached to the intent using a property not the structure. I am afraid if something change on the LUI side (for example renaming the entity) the expression inside the string wont work, but nothing will show that until a tester or a user detects.

Comment: Hmmm, there's an easy to get the values from adaptive expressions into the C# realm, but there's no way that I know of to detect those kind of changes other than testing. I'll post an answer with more details in a little while.

Answer (score 2):

Just to set up a little context, you have to keep in mind that adaptive dialogs and traditional dialogs kind of live in different realms and that you use them in different ways.

You can can use a traditional dialog from an adaptive dialog but you can't (or at least I haven't figured out how to) do it the other way around.

Adaptive dialogs are declarative, managed by the `DialogManager` and traditional dialogs are imperative, managed mostly by your code.

You can add custom code in an adaptive dialog definition by using the `CodeAction` dialog and access any property defined in an adaptive property assignment. So you could define this code action, after your `SetProperty()` action:

```cs
new CodeAction(async (dialogContext, options) =>
{
    // this is the way to get a value from adaptive dialog's state, you can "deserialize" to whatever type
    var userName = dialogContext.State.GetValue<string>("conversation.find.phone.userName");

    // you can also set any property and use it later from any adaptive expression
    dialogContext.State.SetValue("conversation.find.phone.firstName", userName.Split()[0]);

    return await dialogContext.EndDialogAsync(options);
}),
```

To be able to both get and set properties and use them in "the other side".

Anyway I'm not sure that will do for what you want to achieve, but at least is a way to transfer values between both "realities" .

**UPDATE**: I published a [post in my blog](https://www.coderepo.blog/posts/integration-testing-with-adaptive-dialogs-in-bot-framework-v4/) a couple of days ago, that might help with adaptive dialogs, specially in the testing part.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Meanwhile I run into the following: how to add a codeAction to a .dialog file? As I understand your answer is very usable when I build up the adaptive dialog from code.

Comment: But my sample targets how to get the entity value (from a compiled and verified code) and write to a property. Your sample covers something else.

Comment: As for adding a CodeAction to a .dialog file, I've never tried that but it looks like there's no way to do it. However, there's a way to define a custom action that should work just as well, because both inherit from `Dialog`. I haven't tried this (I will for sure ) but this article looks promising: [Add custom actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-add-custom-action?tabs=csharp).

Comment: As for getting the entity values, if I got you right, the key point is that if you're working with adaptive dialogs, you get the recognizer result as a dynamic object that you can get from the `turn` state. And the generated class is meant to be used with traditional dialogs. Anyway having a generated class or deserializing to a `RecognizerResult` object won't help you if the entity name changes in the LUIS model or if you add a role to entity in the LUIS model.

Comment: Thank you for your kind and detail answers Miguel! :)

Comment: Well, hope that, at least, I could help somehow 